# Spring Boot + Apache Camel HTTP component crashes at start: missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-boot

Just taking Spring-Boot for a spin and decided to mix in Camel because I need some arcane Headers work in the rest client I am working on. Setting up the application was fine until I added the camel-http component to my POM, then I get this on init:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
```

I've havent got the first idea of where to start to look for the problem. I gather Spring Boot will look up the classpath and try to wire stuff up, so is there a way for the to block the Camel packages from being acted on or something of the sort?

Complete log of the start up in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/vantroy/8511855)

Here's my main aplication code:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    private static ApplicationContext ctx;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        //Right outta Spring 4 docs
        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");
        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
        //---

        // FIXME: ugly hack to allow some POC woek while wait for proper Camel/Spring4 unit tests fix.
        Application app = new Application();
        app.executeTests();

    }

    /**
     * Dev QOL - unit tests are broken for now, see:
     * https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7074
     * <p/>
     * Waiting for fix (Too lay to checkout and build my own Camel)
     */
    private void executeTests() throws Exception {
        testAuth();
    }

    @Bean
    DefaultCamelContext camelCtx() throws Exception {
        DefaultCamelContext camel = new DefaultCamelContext();
        camel.addRoutes(cryptsyRouteBuilder());
        camel.start();
        return camel;
    }

    @Bean
    public CryptsyRouteBuilder cryptsyRouteBuilder() throws Exception{
        CryptsyRouteBuilder bean = new CryptsyRouteBuilder();
        bean.setCryptsy(cryptsy());
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public Cryptsy cryptsy() throws IOException {
        return new Cryptsy();
    }

    protected void testAuth() throws Exception {
        ProducerTemplate producer = camelCtx().createProducerTemplate();
        producer.requestBody("direct:start", "Why, hullo there", String.class);
    }


}
```

And my POM dependencies:

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Camel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-javaconfig</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Assorted -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <start-class>xxx.xxxx.Application</start-class>
        <camel.version>2.12.2</camel.version>
    </properties>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception is telling you that Spring Boot thinks you want to build a web server, but can't find the right dependencies on the classpath. The most obvious reason for that in your case would be that the HTTP dependencies you added included Servlet APIs. I see no reason why you need that for a client app, but only you would know whether you need it or not. Maybe you can exclude it?

If you do need the Servlet dependencies and just want to explicitly tell Boot that you aren't creating a web application you can set the property `spring.main.web_environment=false`, or use the `SpringApplication` (or `SpringApplicationBuilder`) API directly to set the same flag. See [docs here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/docs/howto.md#create-a-non-web-application) for background information.